# Magento2 remove dupliacte URL of products

Tags: magento2, seo

Actual URL

https://xyz.com/a5-stapled-brochures.html

Duplicate URL:

https://xyz.com/catalog/product/view/id/484/s/a6-stapled-brochures-1/category/35/

How to remove Duplicate URLs?